# How to pass URL string in .desktop file in quotes

Tags: linux, command-line, arguments, .desktop, xdg-open

I installed WhatsApp Desktop via Wine and I am trying to associate `whatsapp://` links with it.

Executing the following via command line works and starts a chat with the phone number `+1234567890`:

```
env WINEPREFIX="/home/mike/WhatsAppDesktopWine" wine C:\\users\\mike\\AppData\\Roaming\\Microsoft\\Windows\\Start\ Menu\\Programs\\WhatsApp\\WhatsApp.lnk "whatsapp://send/?phone=%2B1234567890&text&type=phone_number&app_absent=0"
```

I edited my `~.config/mimeapps.list` file and added:

```
x-scheme-handler/whatsapp=~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/WhatsApp/WhatsApp.desktop
```

WhatsApp.desktop contains the following line:

```
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/mike/WhatsAppDesktopWine" wine C:\\\\users\\\\mike\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows\\\\Start\\ Menu\\\\Programs\\\\WhatsApp\\\\WhatsApp.lnk
```

I then added  `"%u"` at the end, so the full line is

```
Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/mike/WhatsAppDesktopWine" wine C:\\\\users\\\\mike\\\\AppData\\\\Roaming\\\\Microsoft\\\\Windows\\\\Start\\ Menu\\\\Programs\\\\WhatsApp\\\\WhatsApp.lnk "%u"
```

However it is not passing the URL to the command.

Answer (score 0):

The final `Exec` line **should** work, however I found out that `xdg-open` caches the contents of the `.desktop` files. I'm not sure how long the caching is for, however the following seemed clear the cache me:

First, copy the .desktop entry to a temporary location:

```
cp -a ./.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/WhatsApp/WhatsApp.desktop ./.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/WhatsApp/WhatsApp2.desktop
```

Then in mimeapps.list, change the entry to the copied location:

```
x-scheme-handler/whatsapp=~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/WhatsApp/WhatsApp2.desktop
```

Then execute:

```
xdg-open "whatsapp://send/?phone=%2B1234567890&text&type=phone_number&app_absent=0"
```

And finally, you can revert the changes and delete the copied file.